# Git: Pushing to repo error. (Error updating submodules)

Tags: git, github

All of a sudden git stopped working on my (private) repo.

I'm getting this error screen:

[image]

I have checked the account on my github client (this is on OSX) and the login is OK.

Any suggestions, on how to solve this ?

Comment: restart your computer, and make sure that your ssk key match. they might have gotten corrupted

Comment: I have restarted already and the Git app automatically *at least so it said* updated the SSH key

Comment: Would git work (`git pull` or `git submodule update`) from the command-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems that what happened was this:

The Git Application was trying to sync the repository to another (older abandoned) repo that I had previously.

I don't know why and how the github app did end up doing this, but I ended up removing the local repository, cloning the remote and manually pasting the new files on the local repo and then sync again to solve this.